Triying to read an excel file greater than 100 MB with XLSX
I'm triying to read an excel file with a size of 103 MB using this code of XLSX pacakge from npm:
const options: XLSX.ParsingOptions = { cellDates: true, dateNF: "dd/mmmm/yyyy hh:ss:MMMM", raw: true };

const buff = fs.readFileSync(fileLocation);

const workbook = XLSX.read(buff, options);

const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

const rango = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']!);

It does not work. The app do nothing, not even an error. How can I do it?

It is probably worth taking a look at the Excel file in some other environment to see why it is quite so large. Try binary chop on file size to see how big a file the XLSX package can actually handle. Odd that there is no error msg does it hang, crash or what does actually happen? If it is a modern Excel file you can rename it as .zip and take a look at the directory structure with any ZIP tool to see exactly what is there.

Making a research I found that an option to read the file is dense: true, that with alow you to work with an excel that have arrays of arrays, and in that way the XLSX read the file. Now I have to adapt the process to this scenario. But, my new question is: ¿Why it can read the file in one way but not in the other?

could you share your full code ?

I will edit the code and show you, but basically it is the line up there.
